# Integrating in regions

Tags: regions, calculus-and-analysis

I have three rectangles of the same size:

```
s1 = Rectangle[{-(b/2), -(h/2)}, {b/2, h/2}]
s2 = Rectangle[{-(h/2), h/2}, {h/2, h/2 + b}]
s3 = Rectangle[{-(h/2), -(h/2)}, {h/2, -(h/2) - b}]
```

which I combine into a region:

```
r = RegionUnion[Region /@ {s1, s2, s3}]
```

This is a simple symmetrical I-beam-ish shape. When I integrate this:

```
Simplify[Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] r], {0 < b < h}]
```

I get 2 *bh*. I should get 3 *bh*. Also,

```
Simplify[Integrate[y, {x, y} \[Element] r], {0 < b < h}]
```

should be zero, since it's symmetric about the x-axis. Mathematica gives me:

```
1/2 b h (b + h)
```

Any ideas? Mathematica 12.0.0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original `s3` was an incorrectly specified rectangle because `-(h/2) - b = ymax < ymin = -(h/2)`. From the docs for [Rectangle](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html),

> `Rectangle[{xmin,ymin},{xmax,ymax}]`
>   represents an axis-aligned filled rectangle from `{xmin,ymin}` to `{xmax,ymax}`.

Therefore integrating over `s3Broken` gives `Undefined`. Reordering the corrdinates fixes this issue.

```
s1 = Rectangle[{-(b/2), -(h/2)}, {b/2, h/2}];
s2 = Rectangle[{-(h/2), h/2}, {h/2, h/2 + b}];
s3 = Rectangle[{-(h/2), -(h/2) - b}, {h/2, -(h/2)}];

s3Broken = Rectangle[{-(h/2), -(h/2)}, {h/2, -(h/2) - b}];

r = RegionUnion[Region /@ {s1, s2, s3}];

Simplify[Integrate[y, {x, y} \[Element] s3Broken], {0 < b < h}] // Print;
Simplify[Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] r], {0 < b < h}] // Print;
Simplify[Integrate[y, {x, y} \[Element] r], {0 < b < h}] // Print;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY6xCsIwEIZ3n@IfFVNqdVRBBAc3UZxih1RiE2xTSTJYSp@9nlEXKYJDcnfc9/1JKbySpfD6LLrOJVhiL89emLyQvImGWTwdMURDRbVlaGhmoKFN5wM3/aZVoJ9rQtUbxRhZwGf9@KsiIupjvd8jiay1ra7S/HK/vBD1dG2Qcl2Zo6GLv3rEKzQuYXBkuFkgD7q8FfpS863xMrfCS15T6J2hbnHim0KW0vgUn9@ktJxggYyOalPEMXZWGz/vS0r6kuxfEfV/EV33AA)

Comment: Interesting. It plots correctly in `Graphics`. Thanks.